# Incorrect password in SQL injection

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection

I Found a SQL Injection in the Username field with SQL query 1'or'1'='1'-- -
and I have provided those in pictures
If I type the same query in the password it shows an incorrect password what would be the reason for it?

[Images of SQL error]

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They're completely different products.  Your error hints at SQL Server since you're using SqlClient, but there are plenty of times that that gets used incorrectly when using a MySQL backend.  Please edit your tags to reflect what you are actually using.

Comment: If you properly parameterize your queries this wouldn't be an issue. The fact that you are getting this error is an indication of a MAJOR problem with the way you are querying your database. Stop munging string together and executing them. Read, understand and start using parameterized queries.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you're storing plain text passwords either; another fatal flaw in any application.

Comment: what does "type the same query in the password" mean?  show your code, please

Answer (score 2):

just google "prevent sql injection"

And remember that everyone

The username is probably from a registration page.
The Error is indicative of bad coding practices.  We are all guilty of that at some point in our development career.

You need to go through all your queries on the site and change them to use Parameters, instead of concatenating.

Bad EX:

```
CommandString = "Select a from b where b.col = " & Variable
```

Good EX:

```
Dim command As SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select a from b where b.col = @Variable", connection)
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Variable", Variable))
```

Also, it would be a good idea to make it a Stored procedure.

additionally, make sure that the SQL User that the site uses has restricted permissions (can't drop or truncate tables, and only has access to that DB)